# PHP / MySQL: How to store Select results in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, dictionary, key

I am new to PHP and MySQL and hope someone can help me with this.

I have a MySql db with a table "`TranslationsMain`" and the following PHP query. 
This returns all the items from column "`German`" (incl. the corresponding ID) from the db table and works correctly so far.

Instead of echoing the whole list (I just did this here for testing), **how can I store the results in an array in a way that each item within the array is stored with its value and a unique ID + how I can I echo specific items from this array by referring to their ID ?

**Example:**
I would like to echo the item value for ID "`xyz`" from this array (without calling the db again since this will be needed for multiple items on the page).

**My PHP:**

```
<?php 
    require_once("includes/header.php");

    $tblTranslations = "TranslationsMain";  

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if($conn->connect_error){
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $tblTranslations;
    $translations = $conn->query($sql);

    // for testing only
    if($translations->num_rows > 0){
        echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Translation</th></tr>";
        while($translation = $translations->fetch_assoc()){
            echo "<tr><td>" . $translation["ID"] . "</td><td>" . $translation["German"] . "</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }else{
        echo "0 results";
    }

    $conn->close();
?>
```

**Update:**
What I am looking for here is how to create a two dimensional array and how to fetch from it.

Many thanks in advance, 
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($translations->num_rows > 0){
   $result_arr = array();
    echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Translation</th></tr>";
    while($translation = $translations->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<tr><td>" . $translation["ID"] . "</td><td>" . $translation["German"] . "</td></tr>";
    $result_arr[] = $translation;
    }
    echo "</table>";
}else{
    echo "0 results";
}


// now you can iterate $result_arr 


foreach($result_arr as $row){
   echo "<tr><td>" . $row["ID"] . "</td><td>" . $row["German"] . "</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - This looks very good ! I only used the table for testing but wouldn't this later on as I just need to echo single values then. With your approach and my IDs being incrementing numbers how would I echo e.g. the value for the item with ID = "5" ?

Comment: your id = 5 will be the fifth row of the table right... so when creating the array the 5th row is assigned to 5th sub array and if you want to use the value of id = 5 . you need something like this $result_arr[4]["value']. now if you want you can assign user defined keys to your array. rather than by default keys this way you will be able to access the data like this $result_arr[5]['value'] for 5th ID and $result_arr[6]['value'] for 6th ID

Comment: Thanks again ! I think the key solution wouldn't work for me here since then it becomes difficult to know which item has which ID and this may change when more items get added to the db. What I am looking for is a way where I fetch both the ID and the value from the db and then save both of them in the array so that I can fetch it from there. Sorry if I am not explaining it well, still all new to me.

Comment: I updated the post to better describe what I am looking for here.

Comment: the key solution will work for you no matter how much items are added to db. bcoz the key will be unique always and i have done something like this a long time ago and its still working fine without any bugs or complaints